# App Engine Launcher and Django

Tags: google-app-engine

I have running an APP on Google App Engine that I developed in Python and used Django template  data display. I used Launcher to test and deploy. I did not use such Django verbs as {% url etc etc %}.  It was all good and well.

I now need to do some work on an existing APP on Google App Engine that is Django based and uses the many more Django verbs.

It fails to run on Launcher.

I read that you use something like manage.py runserver and I think Launcher is not capable of supporting my development testing on this one. Is there a way so Launcher can?

I am not quite sure what environment for test I am going to use ??

Comment: You need to provide more info.. what exactly is the error..?

Comment: The error is:    Caught SyntaxError while rendering: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:\.......

Comment: The question is really Django on Launcher how do you get it to use the right libarries.

Comment: I have found the answer you ad the line # coding: utf-8   to all the Python programs including helper.py.  You must used latest or above 1.6 for Google Launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer you ad the line # coding: utf-8 to all the Python programs including helper.py. You must used latest or above 1.6 for Google Launcher.

Comment: thanks --- where do i need to add the line?  is it a comment?